# Testing Java code and previewing the SQL statement

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

The following is a Java (Hibernate) Method. How can I write a test for it? I want the test method to return a SQL statement.The code reference a lot of other classes and packages which already exist. Ignore these and just show me how to integrate them in my test program.

```
@Override
public AppTacticalSubUnit returnByCode(String code) throws MyOwnDAOException {
    Session session = getSession();
    UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
    try {
        unitOfWork.beginTransaction(session);
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(AppTacticalSubUnit.class);
        criteriaAppTacticalSubUnit.add(Restrictions.eq("code", code));
        criteriaAppTacticalSubUnit.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
        setJoinFetches(criteria);
        AppTacticalSubUnit ret = (AppTacticalUnit) criteria.uniqueResult();
        unitOfWork.commit();
        return ret;
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        unitOfWork.rollback();
        throw new ObelixxDAOException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

private void setJoinFetches(Criteria criteria) {
    criteria.setFetchMode("appTacticalUnit.spaceOpsAreaServiceType", FetchMode.JOIN);
    criteria.setFetchMode("appTacticalSubUnit.spaceOpsAreaServiceType.assExternalServiceType", FetchMode.JOIN);
    criteria.setFetchMode("appTacticalSubUnit.spaceOpsAreaServiceType.assExternalServiceType.lookupServiceType", FetchMode.JOIN);
    criteria.setFetchMode("appTacticalSubUnit.spaceOpsAreaServiceType.assExternalServiceType.lookupExternalServiceType", FetchMode.JOIN);
    criteria.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
    criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("name"));
```

I have started something like this:

```
package na.co.sab.vitalix.db.dao;
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.FetchMode;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.criterion.CriteriaSpecification;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Order;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.hsqldb.Session;
import na.co.sab.datashare.util.UnitOfWork;
import na.co.sab.vitalix.db.exception.MyOwnDAOException;
import na.co.sab.vitalix.db.util.HibernateOltpSessionUtil;

public class AppTacticalSubUnitTest {

//protected static final org.apache.log4j.Logger LOG = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(AppOTacticalSubUnitTest.class);
static protected HibernateOltpSessionUtil dataShareInstance;
public static void initializeVitalixOnHsql() throws Exception {
    initializeVitalixOnHsql(true);
```

Comment: instead of inspecting the generated sql, you could try dbUnit to write some higher level tests

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this article http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-get-jpqlsql-string seems like it describes what you want.

The idea is to use `org.hibernate.Query#getQueryString()` method.